# PHPMailer adding images using the FOR loop

Tags: php, image, email, phpmailer

I have this PHP code:

```php
for($x = 0; $x < count($obrazy); $x++) 
{ 
   $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($obrazy[$x], 'tel'.$x); 
}
```

the variable "obrazy" is a table storing path (link to the image) e.g. "obraz/zdjecie.png". I need to do this with a loop because the array of obrazy can have a different size each time. The above loop does not work for me, because when I want to show this image in the mail, nothing is displayed.

```php
$iterator = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat)) 
{      
         $mail->Body = $mail->Body.'//..........

                <img src="cid:tel'.$iterator.'" style="

                    width: 160px;
                    display: block;
                    float: left;

                "/> //..........
           ';

          $iterator++;
}
```

"// ......" means another part of the code that does not matter to the question being asked. The while loop must be because I extract different data from the database. Everything works only the images do not want to be displayed in the email, even if instead of "$iterator" I enter the number. Links to the image contained in the table are RELIABLE for the PHP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are your path or permissions are wrong; Check the return value from `addEmbeddedImage`:

```
if (!$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($obrazy[$x], 'tel'.$x)) {
  echo 'Failed to attach '. $obrazy[$x];
}
```

It's probably a good idea to turn the path into an absolute one, for example by saying something like  `__DIR__ . '/' . $obrazy[$x]` instead of just the relative path.

It may be that your current working directory is not where you think it is. Try doing it like this:

```
if (!$mail->AddEmbeddedImage(getcwd() . '/' . $obrazy[$x], 'tel'.$x)) {
  echo 'Failed to attach '. getcwd() . '/' . $obrazy[$x];
}
```

Then it will show you the full path of the files it's failing to find, and you can check whether they are correct.

Comment: Failed to attach grafika/mate%2010%20pro.png

Comment: Return False ;(

Comment: Right, so check that the rest of the path is correct - for example try adding `echo getcwd();` to see where it's currently running from - your path needs to be relative to that.

Comment: I'm working on xampp localhost so how do I use the absolute path?

Comment: It's the local file system path that's wrong, not a URL.

Comment: I've already checked this with var_dump and the path is actually 100%

Comment: If the path is correct, then it will be permissions, as I said. But double check your path anyway - if `getcwd() . $obrazy[$x]` is not the correct path, you know what to do.

Comment: I did not give any url addresses, it works like this:

send.php
|
-obrazy
    |
    -zdjecie.png
    -animal.png

in the array I have saved "obrazy/animal.png"

Comment: I made a small edit - you can see it's missing a `/` in the path. If it still fails, check permissions and ownership of the `obraz` folder and the image files. Also, your filename contains a space which has been unnecessarily URL-encoded as `%20`, which will not match the actual path. Spaces are allowed in paths, so long as they are escaped (with `\\`) or quoted.

Comment: Failed to attach C:\xampp\htdocs\projektobrazy/animal.pngMessage has been sent

Comment: Bah, sorry, you're on windows - change the `/` to a \ - you want your path to come out as `C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\obrazy\animal.png`.

Comment: is the problem because I download this path from the database and use it in js files, there is no other way ???

Comment: You can search & replace it in the path you get from the db - for example `str_replace('/', '\', $obrazy[$x])`

Comment: Wait 30 minutes i check it ok

Comment: ```str_replace('/', '\ ', $obrazy[$x]);``` syntax error :( if I write ```str_replace('/', '\    ', $obrazy[$x]);``` there is no error, but the image still does not display in the e-mail this space in "\    ".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code, so it's probably an issue with where you have put it. Overall though, none of this changes the basic issue - you need to get the path right.

Comment: relative or absolute? I can put a php file in a graphics file or even better at the top of the document in the top of the path in the array for the image path and then we'll see

Comment: Everything works. The path must be relative to the file. The problem was in the name of the file, in the database I had a saved file name with a space, e.g. ```images/animal dog.png```. I thought it was enough to change the space to ```% 20```, but it did not help. I just changed the space character to ```_``` e.g. ```Images/animal_dog.png``` and everything works. Thank you for helping Synchro :)

Comment: the above my code works 100% just watch out for file names :)